# How do you give an ScheduledExecutor service a maximum time to keep on launching new threads?

Tags: java, timer, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice, executor

Take a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor like the one below. How do you give the executor itself a time window where it can launch new threads. Outside of that time window it should stop launching new threads at a fixed rate.

```
executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable(){}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

For example 1 < window < 3s:

```
if executor has run for <= 1s stop launching thread  
if executor has run for > 1s and < 3s. Start and keep launching thread 
if executor has run for < 3s stop launching thread.
```

Alternatively if the executor could be given a time out that would also work. Note I am not saying giving the thread a timeout, but the executor itself.

I have one solution in adding time tracker in the thread itself but I am wondering if there are more native ways of doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "native" solution.
The better approach would be to (just throwing in my ideas)

- collect and store all `Future<?>`(s) returned from `scheduleAtFixedRate`
- use a job scheduler such as Quartz to start jobs at a specific time / or even another `ScheduledExecutor`
- react to the "events" launched by the Quartz jobs, canceling all the stored `Future<?>`(s) (not shutting down the executor) / changing `Executor` implementation on-the-fly for a no-op custom version

This is a bit impractical. Imho I think you're trying to do something clever which can be solved in more "standard" ways.